# How to use regex to match for number and string?

Tags: ruby, regex, rubular

My variable column could either be a string or a number/float. I need to use my regex to catch both `20000` and `"20000"`. Right now my regex is `/^#{column}$/i` which only catches the string `"20000"`. In addition to this, I need it to stay case insensitive which it currently is.

I am using Mongoid to query a mongo database. The whole query is

```
Mongoid.client("default")["table_name"].find({ field: /^#{row[column]}$/i })
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "match a number with a regex"? -- You can't. You could either just *check if it's a number*, or convert it to a string first. What does `/^#{column}$/i` mean? (What is `column`?)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include that it is a Mongo query. So in my database I could have a value of 20000 which is a number, or I could have `"20000"` and my regex would need to capture both of these values.